# Rabbitmq reload/refresh new certificates without restart

Tags: rabbitmq, ssl-certificate, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmqctl

I am using self signed certificates in my Rabbitmq server and the broker is started successfully with SSL port. I am now trying to renew / use new SSL certificates, SSL key and truststore but I do not want to restart the running rabbitmq server as my application should run continously. I checked online for solutions to refresh / reload the erlang/rabbitmq on the runtime to read/reload these new SSL certificates and I stumbled upon few links where they suggested to use - `rabbitmqctl eval "ssl:stop(), ssl:start()." to reload certs`.

The command worked fine and the new SSL certs were refreshed without rabbitmq restart, but the Consumers / connections were **RESET** because of which my application cannot read the messages from the queues anymore.

Can you please help me with this issue? I like to reload the new SSL certificates  without restarting my rabbitmq or application and the rabbitmq must work fine with my application without any connection reset. 
If not kindly suggest me on how to re-establish the connections back again so that my application runs as expected.

Comment: Hey there, let's make this a ''living dead'' post.

I have the same question. It seem that after updating the certificat and running --->  rabbitmqctl eval "ssl:stop(), ssl:start()." to reload certs

return a OK value from the prompt.

And like you, it seem that connections are RESETED and on top of that, the management interface as long with the API are ''broken'' and no longer accessible...

Is there a documented way on how to do that ?

Please note that this is not a clustered installation.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out newer versions of Erlang auto-update their PEM cache, so all you need to do is put the new certificate in place and then wait for a few minutes.

If you need to force the use of the new certificate sooner, you can use

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'ssl:clear_pem_cache().'
```

And this will reload the certificate **without** disconnecting any publishers or consumers.

Comment: The error I get when I try this is "unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on {name}.localdomain: nxdomain (non-existing domain)". Still researching to find solutions but do you have any ideas?

Comment: @UcheOzoemena still works, you just need to make sure `epmd` is running: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html

Comment: This command (or waiting for a few minutes or even days) does update the certificate but it doesn't update the CA bundle even though it was changed. I did not find how to refresh it without restarting rabbitmq.